# Spring Cloud: Switching from Brixton.M5 to Brixton.SR5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am currently using spring cloud Brixton.M5 version and I want to switch it to release version (SR5).

When I do this, following problem appears:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2RestTemplateConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory de.muenchen.service.security.OAuth2RestTemplateConfig.ribbonClientHttpRequestFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
      at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory de.muenchen.service.security.OAuth2RestTemplateConfig.ribbonClientHttpRequestFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
      at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
      at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

So the RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory is not Autowired anymore. Everything works fine with Brixton.M5 and Brixton.RC1, but starting from Brixton.RC2 - not anymore.

Let me know if additional input is needed.

Comment: Do youu use RestTemplate in your code?

Comment: Can you show your configuration please (classes, properties)? Or even better, publish your sample app somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory` is not enabled by default. You need to set `ribbon.http.client.enabled=true`. The question is, why are you referencing it directly?